# How do I change this code to make it scroll when you come into view?

Tags: jquery, scroll

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".griditem").slice(0, 12).show();
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".griditem:hidden").slice(0, 12).slideDown();
        if ($(".griditem:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});
</script>
```

With this bit of code it currently requires you to press a button to load more divs in, but how do I make it do it automatically when you scroll into view so you don't have to press the button?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWMKZx

Comment: That's because you put it under your `onClick` event handler. You should put it outside of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event listener to the scroll event, so that you can check whenever the user scrolls to the point you want to.

```
var flag = true;
$(document).scroll(function(){
  var st = $(document).scrollTop();
  var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
  var offset = $('#loadMore').offset().top; //You can change #loadMore for whatever element you want to fire the event when the user scrolls to.
  if (st + viewportHeight > offset && flag){ //You can change the number 10. This means "When scrolled 10 pixels more than the top border of #loadMore"
    $('#loadMore').trigger("click");
    flag = false; //This flag is just so that the click doesnt get triggered a lot of times unnecesary.
    window.setTimeout(function(){flag=true;},200);
  }
});
```

Here is the [Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wppexa)

Comment: @AchmedZuzali I have uploaded the codepen now. I also made a slight modification on my code, adding the variable `viewportHeight` which is also needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function loadIt(){
  $(".griditem").slice(0, 12).show();
        $(".griditem:hidden").slice(0, 12).slideDown();
        if ($(".griditem:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
}
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() -20) {
       loadIt();
   }  
});
```

Comment: Can you put it in a codepen because its not working for me